# How to combine simultaneous html pre tags into one pre tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a problem regarding the `<pre>` tags. My HTML editor wraps each line of code into separate `<pre>` tags. For example:

```
<pre>
    var abc = "apple";
</pre>

<pre>
    var def = "ball";
</pre>
```

What I want to do is to wrap both of these pre tags into one:

```
<pre>
    var abc = "apple";
    var def = "ball";
</pre>
```

The wrapping must be of continuous `<pre>` tags because I have other text in between the blocks of these `<pre>` tags.

Comment: Need more information as to the possible relations between pre tags on the page.  Are they nested in some common element?  Can they exist randomly and anywhere on the page?  To what extent can there be space between them?

Comment: The pre tags can exist randomly but they do have a common class. Its like writing several blocks of code with their explanation in between

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach:-

Get the adjascent `pre`s pair, iterate, get the previous with self and get their contents, unwrap them to remove the `pre` wrappers (pair) and wrap all of them (the pair) with fresh new `pre` tag.

```
$('pre').next('pre').each(function () {
   $(this)
          .prev('pre')
          .andSelf()
          .contents()
          .unwrap()
          .wrapAll('<pre/>');
});
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uBvTF/)

Comment: The new line characters in between the texts inside pre tags are not being included... The merging is perfect

Comment: @Anudwigna It takes care of it.. Can you show me a sample fiddle.

Comment: Actually, its a C program that I am trying to post to my website. Each line of code of the C program is wrapped by pre tags. And I am trying wrap the program into one pre tag. I think the problem is with my editor. It is TinyMCE. It wraps each line of the code in pre tags. The JSfiddle did not allow to write C code in pre tags. There was some error

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
    var removed = []
    $("pre").each(function () {
        if (removed.indexOf(this) != -1) {
            return;
        }
        var contents = $(this).html();
        var $nextpre;
        while (($nextpre = $(this).next("pre")) && $nextpre.length > 0) {
            contents += $nextpre.html();
            removed.push($nextpre[0]);
            $nextpre.remove();
        }
        $(this).html(contents);
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/NzuCz/10/)

This is pretty close. It has a problem that `.next()` skips over text nodes, so this merges `<pre>` blocks that are only separated by text, but not other HTML elements.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NzuCz/ with your script the output is identical with and without merge

Comment: I'm getting closer, but now it removes the `<pre>` that it merges, because the next iteration still operates on that node because it was part of the original collection. Need to somehow skip nodes I've seen.

Answer (score 0):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BcF9j/1/)**

```
$(function () {
    var $pre = $('pre + pre');
    $pre.each(function () {
        var $elem = $(this);
        var $before = $elem.prev('pre');

        $elem.contents().unwrap().appendTo($before);
    });
});
```

Comment: This doesn't pick up text nodes. Places them in the wrong spot.

Comment: The above code works for me, but it is not taking up the new line characters in between the texts included inside pre tags

Comment: @Anudwigna check this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BcF9j/3/). First and second `pre` elements have new lines within it. It works for me.

Comment: Actually, its a C program that I am trying to post to my website. Each line of code of the C program is wrapped by pre tags. And I am trying wrap the program into one pre tag. I think the problem is with my editor. It is TinyMCE. It wraps each line of the code in pre tags. The JSfiddle did not allow to write C code in pre tags. There was some error